# Getting details of user without login in flask?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I am new to the flask so I need your help on below query-
I created an Flask application and now I want to get the information of user who opened my website? I am not intrested to create any login page or save user information in database. So it will be very simple like this website will be an Opensource and anyone can access.
So could you please let me know the way by which I can get the information of user who opened the website?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way of getting a user's "information" without logging the user in. If you are not interested in creating a database, you can use a log in with google option and then retrieve the "information" of the user using the Google APIs.

It also depends on what information of the user you want. if its simple like the email or first name or gender etc, google login can help with that.

Check these out:
https://realpython.com/flask-google-login/

You would have to provide more info on what you are doing